# Welch's 100% Grape Juice with Calcium/ yeast

Tags: wine, red-wine, barleywine, country-wine, fruit-wine

I am planning to make a wine using Welch's 100% Grape Juice with Calcium ! 
Is the calcium problem here !

Comment: Could you write more details, what are you worried about exactly, etc.

Comment: Well I was worried about the Calcium in the Welch grape juice ... But Mr Brewchez said no worries from the Calcium but I have to consider the preservatives because it needs more yeast .. I don't know how much yeast  I need to add !

Comment: Feel free to edit your original question to ask for more information about yeast or post another question if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Calcium is not going to be an issue.  The sorbate as a preservative is likely going to be an issue.  Pitch more yeast than you think you need to overcome the preservative.

Comment: I'm planning to make 5 gallons .. how many ounces of wine yeast red star do you think I need .. thank you

Comment: If you're not adding any additional sugar I'd use at least two packs of yeast. Three wouldn't hurt.  Some yeast nutrient would be a good idea too.  You know that table grapes like Concord Grapes make lousy wine right? Most grape juice (certainly Welch's) is made from Concord Grapes.

Comment: I believe in that .. it'll be lousy wine .. but I wonder why in YouTube some guys said it's perfect! That's why I wanna just try it

Comment: Cool.  Let us know how it turns out. I am not curious enough to try it but I am curious. Love it.  Good luck.

Comment: If people say that wine made from Welch is perfect, ask them what other wines they like...  it should be closer to lousy (or nasty) than perfect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have made wine with Welch's grape juice.

I only used one packet of yeast and it turned out very good.  I did wonder if the added calcium in the juice I just bought was going to be an issue.  Now reading the comments, I don't think it will be an issue.
I will write a follow up if I have any issues.

Comment: IMHO this is more a comment than an answer at this stage. Please do [edit] it with more information though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, please add as much details as possible to help answer the question.